# Total number of days between two dates by Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on a query to calculate total no of days between date ranges by year

Table:

```
Start Date    End Date  
01/01/2013    04/30/2014  
11/01/2014    05/31/2015  
06/01/2015    12/31/2015
```

My expected result.

```
2013 - 365  
2014 - 180  
2015 - 365
```

I can do this in multiple steps using temp table. Is there any simple way to do this calculation.

Thanks

Comment: not clear what you are asking how does the first "row" know to ignore the dates in 2014 and the second one know to ignore the dates in 2015 -- is it end of year of start date or end date whichever is lower?

Comment: Why is 2015 - 365?   There's no 01/01/2015 in your sample data.

Comment: @TabAlleman - yes the expected results make no sense in many ways.

Comment: Entire year 2015 is covered by the range.

Comment: I am just trying to find how many days in a particular year is covered by the range. in this case 11/1/2014 - 05/31/2015 covers first 5 months and 06/01/2015 - 12/31/2015 will cover the remaining so in total 365 days in 2015

Answer (score 0):

Okay so try this out:

```
SELECT * INTO #yourTable
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('01/01/2013' AS DATE),CAST('04/30/2014' AS DATE) UNION ALL 
    SELECT '11/01/2014','05/31/2015' UNION ALL  
    SELECT '06/01/2015','12/31/2015'
) A(StartDate,EndDate);

DECLARE @MaxEndDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM #yourTable);

WITH CTE_Dates
AS
(
    SELECT MIN(StartDate) dates
    FROM #yourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(Day,1,dates)
    FROM CTE_Dates
    WHERE dates < @MaxEndDate
)

SELECT YEAR(dates) yr,COUNT(DATES) cnt
FROM #yourTable A
CROSS APPLY(SELECT dates FROM CTE_Dates WHERE dates BETWEEN A.startDate AND A.EndDate) CA
GROUP BY YEAR(dates)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Entire year 2015 is covered by the range. So I would expect 365 days for 2015.

Comment: I edited my code. I think I got it at least very close this time.

Answer (score -1):

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2013', '4/30/2014')
```

This will give you what you are looking for. Just repeat for all the dates that you want.

This gives the number of times the midnight boundary is crossed between the two dates. You may decide to need to add one to this if you're including both dates in the count - or subtract one if you don't want to include either date.

Comment: Clearly this does not work since `DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2013', '4/30/2014')` is not 365 which is what the OP said was the expected result.